# Windows 10 connecting to Windows NT 4.0 "The remote device or resource won’t accept the connection"

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-xp

I have a Windows 10 Pro 2004 desktop computer attempting to connect to a Windows NT 4.0 computer and throwing the error:

> The remote device or resource won’t accept the connection

I receive the error by typing into File Explorer:

\10.10.71.62

or

\10.10.71.62\D$

For the purpose of this question, the Windows 10 computer is in a network with two Windows NT 4.0 computers. The last time the Windows 10 computer received an update was about 2-weeks ago.

The Windows 10 computer was able to successfully connect yesterday to both Windows NT 4.0 computers, as it has for years now. The Win10 computer can STILL connect to one of the Windows XP computers with no issues. It is the other WinNT computer that has the issue.

I restarted both computers.

I am able to ping the problematic WinNT computer from the Win10 box and ping the Win10 box from the WinNT box. There are no IP conflicts.

I checked Services on the WinNT box and Computer Browser and other relevant services are started and running. I found a google article stating to check a handful of services and those were running. I cannot find the article now, so no link, sorry.

There are no proxies. I saw one article that statement to reset IE Options in the Advanced tab to defaults, which I did. That did not help. I did not expect that to.

**UPDATE**:

The original version of this post mentioned Windows XP, which was a mistake on my part. The computer has Windows NT 4.0. It is not possible to upgrade that PC, because it runs the AMADA software, which ties to hardware.

Up until recently the Windows 10 desktop connected nicely to the box, which means that SMB is installed.

The single response so far mentioned disabling NLA, however Windows NT does not have Remote Desktop, nor do I want to use it. I checked and installing RDP on WinNT is not possible.

I also suggested using sneaker net and taking a USB stick to move files back and forth. It turns out that WinNT does not support USB, so that is out, not that that idea got a warm reception, when I posed it.

I am not sure what changed, but I suspect something on Windows 10, as the Windows NT box has not been updated in a while.

I should add that connecting the WinNT box to the company domain is not possible, as our Windows Server 2019 domain controller does not support NT. As such, the Network Login service does not start, but that has not been started, if ever, and Windows 10 was able to connect just fine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common mistake when setting up a local network that has Windows 10 and Windows XP computers. On a Windows 10 computer, the Network applet does not show Windows XP computers.

The reason is that in Windows 10, by default, support for the SMB v 1 protocol is disabled. And Windows XP uses this version of the protocol for network exchange.

The problem can be solved simply. You need to install the SMB v 1 component. To do this, you need to open the Windows 10 settings (via the Start menu), and there open the "Applications and features" settings group. In this group you need to find and open "Programs and Features"
In the list of programs, you need to open "Turn on or off by Windows component".
In the list of components, you need to find and mark the components "SMB Client and Server 1".
After installing the components, you need to check that the same Workgroup is specified in the computer names settings. And on a Windows 10 computer, disable password-protected sharing, unless of course you need to restrict access on your local network.

Comment: The Win10 box has the SMB Client 1 features enabled. I am still able to view shares on the other WinXP box and up until yesterday the problematic box. With respect to domains, the Win10 box is part of the company domain (Win2019 domain controller), however the WinXP is not, as I recall, too old. That was a nice try, though.

Comment: Read this - https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2014/06/25/windows-2012-rds-ne-podklyuchayutsya-rdp-klienty-windows-xp/

Comment: I updated my question. I was wrong on the OS. It is Windows NT 4.0, even older than XP. NT does not support RDP, so nothing to disable. I also do not want to use RDP, but that is beside the point. See the updated question and the update for further details.

Comment: It is possible that with the next update of Windows 10, the registry parameter HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Netlogon\Parametersreturned\AllowNT4Crypto (Value Type - REG_DWORD) to the default  state - 0 (Disable). 
If you disable this policy setting (0), Net Logon will not allow the negotiation and use of older cryptography algorithms.
If you enable this policy setting (1), Net Logon will allow the negotiation and use of older cryptography algorithms compatible with Windows NT 4.0. However, using the older algorithms represents a potential security risk.